# convert number to string returns empty if number 0

Tags: javascript

Trying to convert string to a number, works fine apart from when the number is zero it returns an empty string;

I understand 0 is false, but I just need a neat way of it returning the string "0"

I'm using:

```
const num = this.str ? this.str.toString() : '' ;
```

I even thought of using es6 and simply `${this.str}` but that didn't work

Comment: So just always call `.toString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because 0 is "false-y" in JavaScript, as you've already figured out, you can't utilized it in a conditional. Instead, ask yourself what the conditional is ***really*** trying to solve.

Are you worried about null / undefined values? Perhaps this is better:

```
const num = (typeof this.str !== "undefined" && this.str !== null) ? this.str.toString() : "";
```

Odds are you really only care if `this.str` is a **`Number`**, and in all other cases want to ignore it. What if `this.str` is a `Date`, or an `Array`? Both `Date` and `Array` have a `.toString()` method, which means you may have some weird bugs crop up if one slips into your function unexpectedly.

So a better solution may be:

```
const num = (typeof this.str === "number") ? this.str.toString() : "";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also put your code in a try catch block

```
const num = ''
try {
  num = this.str.toString();
} catch(e) {
  // Do something here if you want.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to given answers - if you do:

```js
x >> 0
```

you will convert `anything` to a `Number`

```js
'7' >> 0 // 7
'' >> 0 // 0
true >> 0 // 1
[7] >> 0 // 7
```

It's a *right shift bit operation*. You can do magic with this in many real life cases, like described in [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/interesting-use-cases-for-javascript-bitwise-operators/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the zero (number) that I wanted to converted to a string (which was the value of an option in a select element) was a value in an enum.

So I did this, since the enum was generated by another process and I could not change it:

```
  let stringValue = '';
  if (this.input.enumValue === 0) {
    stringValue = '0'; 
  } else {
    stringValue = this.input.enumValue.toString();
  }
```